# Meu programa roda apenas até a segunda iteração, depois recebo o NoSuchElementException da classe Scanner

Tags: java, scanner

Bom dia, estou praticando com JDBC e fiz uma classe Contato, uma classe Menu e a classe Principal para testar, mas estou com o problema descrito no título:

Classe Menu

```
package controller;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.postgresql.util.PSQLException;

import model.Contato;

public abstract class Menu {
    
    private final static String MENU = """
            --- Projeto Agenda ---
            
            1) Iniciar
            2) Encerrar
            
            """;
    private final static String AGENDA_MENU = """
            
            1) Criar Novo Contato
            2) Localizar Contato por ID
            3) Atualizar Contato por ID
            4) Apagar Contato por ID
            5) Encerrar aplicação
            
            """;
    
    public static void exibirMenu() {
        
        try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            System.out.println(MENU);
            int opcao = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
            while(opcao != 2) {
                String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Agenda";
                
                System.out.println("Entre com o nome de usuário:");
                String usuario = scan.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Entre com a senha:");
                String senha = scan.nextLine();
                
                try (Connection conexao = DriverManager.getConnection(url, usuario, senha)){
                    System.out.println("Conexão bem-sucedida ao banco de dados!");
                    Contato contato = new Contato();
                    opcao = 0;
                    
                        while (opcao != 5) {
                            
                            System.out.println(AGENDA_MENU);
                            opcao = scan.nextInt();
                            
                            switch(opcao) {
                            case 1:
                                contato.criarContato(conexao);
                                break;
                                
                            case 2:
                                contato.lerContato(conexao);
                                break;
                                
                            case 3:
                                contato.atualizarContato(conexao);
                                break;
                                
                            case 4:
                                contato.apagarContato(conexao);
                                break;
                                
                            default:
                                System.out.println("Agenda fechada.");
                                opcao = 2;
                                break;
                                
                            }
                        }
                    
                } catch(PSQLException e) { 
                    if(e.getMessage().contains("password authentication failed")) {
                        
                        System.out.println("Credenciais inválidas. \nVerifique nome de usuário e senha \ne tente novamente.");
                    
                    } else {
                        
                        System.out.println("Erro ao conectar ao banco de dados." + e.getMessage());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }catch (SQLException e) {
                    
                    System.out.println("Erro ao conectar ao banco de dados:" + e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Classe Contato

```
package model;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Contato {

    //private int id;
    private String nome;
    private String telefone;

    public void criarContato(Connection conexao) throws SQLException {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO contatos (nome, telefone) VALUES (?, ?)";

        try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)){
            try (PreparedStatement ps = conexao.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS)) {
                System.out.println("Entre com o nome do contato:");
                nome = scan.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Entre com o telefone do contato:");
                telefone = scan.nextLine();
                ps.setString(1, nome);
                ps.setString(2, telefone);
                ps.executeUpdate();

                try (ResultSet chavesGeradas = ps.getGeneratedKeys()) {
                    if(chavesGeradas.next()) {

                        int idInserido = chavesGeradas.getInt(1);
                        System.out.println("Contato inserido com sucesso!");
                        System.out.println("ID: " + idInserido);
                        System.out.println("Nome: " + nome);
                        System.out.println("Telefone: " + telefone.substring(0, telefone.length() - 4) + "-" + telefone.substring(telefone.length() - 4));

                    }
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("Erro na criação do contato!" + e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } 

    }

    public void lerContato(Connection conexao) throws SQLException {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM contatos WHERE id = ?";

        try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)){
            try(PreparedStatement ps = conexao.prepareStatement(sql)) {
                System.out.println("Entre com o ID que deseja buscar");
                int id = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
                ps.setInt(1, id);

                try (ResultSet resultSet = ps.executeQuery()) {

                    if(resultSet.next()) {
                        int contatoId = resultSet.getInt("id");
                        String nome = resultSet.getString("nome");
                        String telefone = resultSet.getString("telefone");

                        System.out.println("ID: " + contatoId);
                        System.out.println("Nome: " + nome);
                        System.out.println("Telefone: " + telefone);
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Nenhum contato encontrado com o ID informado.");
                    }
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    System.out.println("Erro ao executar a consulta: " + e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("Problemas com a busca. " + e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } 


    }

    public void atualizarContato(Connection conexao) throws SQLException {
        String sql = "UPDATE contatos SET nome = ?, telefone = ? WHERE id = ?";
        

        try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)){
            try(PreparedStatement ps = conexao.prepareStatement(sql)) {
                System.out.println("Informe o ID do contato que deseja atualizar");
                int id = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
                System.out.println("Informe novo nome:");
                String novoNome = scan.nextLine();
                ps.setString(1, novoNome);
                System.out.println("Informe novo telefone:");
                String novoTelefone = scan.nextLine();
                ps.setString(2, novoTelefone);

                ps.setInt(3, id);

                ps.executeUpdate();

                System.out.println("Contato atualizado com sucesso!");

            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("Problemas ao atualizar contato." + e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } 
    }

    public void apagarContato(Connection conexao) throws SQLException {
        String sql = "DELETE FROM contatos WHERE id = ?";

        try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)){
            try (PreparedStatement ps = conexao.prepareStatement(sql)) {
                System.out.println("Informe o ID do contato que deseja apagar:");
                int id = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());

                ps.setInt(1, id);
                ps.executeUpdate();

                System.out.println("Contato apagado com sucesso!");

            } catch(SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("Problemas ao apagar contato. " + e.getMessage() );
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Classe TesteConexao

```
package controller;

public class TesteConexao {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Menu.exibirMenu();

    }

}
```

Erro Apresentado

```
--- Projeto Agenda ---

1) Iniciar
2) Encerrar


1
Entre com o nome de usuário:
postgres
Entre com a senha:
1234
Conexão bem-sucedida ao banco de dados!

1) Criar Novo Contato
2) Localizar Contato por ID
3) Atualizar Contato por ID
4) Apagar Contato por ID
5) Encerrar aplicação


1
Entre com o nome do contato:
pessoa1
Entre com o telefone do contato:
1234567890
Contato inserido com sucesso!
ID: 12
Nome: pessoa1
Telefone: 123456-7890

1) Criar Novo Contato
2) Localizar Contato por ID
3) Atualizar Contato por ID
4) Apagar Contato por ID
5) Encerrar aplicação


Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
    at controller.Menu.exibirMenu(Menu.java:52)
    at controller.TesteConexao.main(TesteConexao.java:9)
```

Alguém pode me ajudar?
Obrigado!

Comment: `try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in))` - aqui vc usa o [*try-with-resources*](/q/172909/112052), que ao final do bloco fecha automaticamente o `Scanner`, o que faz com que também feche o `System.in`. Isso quer dizer que qualquer tentativa de ler depois disso falhará, pois mesmo que vc crie outro `Scanner`, não adianta porque o `System.in` estará fechado. Em vez disso, crie apenas um `Scanner` e use-o por toda a aplicação (por exemplo, passando-o como argumento para os métodos `criarContato`, `lerContato`, etc).

Comment: Outro problema é misturar `nextInt` com `nextLine`, isso costuma dar problema (veja [aqui](/q/262976/112052) e [aqui](https://hkotsubo.github.io/blog/2022-06-15/lendo-dados-teclado-em-java-usando-a-classe-scanner) para entender melhor); No caso sugiro usar somente `nextLine` (tem uma linha que vc faz `opcao = scan.nextInt()`, para evitar o problema citado troque para `opcao = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine())`)

Comment: muito obrigado, resolveu o problema!